# PythonTeX - duplicate entry in .pytxcode file

Tags: errors, python

I have started using pythontex with latex and have run into a situation where it appears that when the code is stripped out of the tex document there is some sort of numbering issue.

Here is a minimal example:

```
%! program = pdflatex

\documentclass[oneside,11pt,letterpaper,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{pycode}
import math

Temp="Text" 

def tTableData():
    tTempTableData="Text 1 & Text 2 \\\\ \n Text 3 & Text 4 \\\\ \n"
    return tTempTableData

\end{pycode}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \py{Temp}
\end{itemize}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{c c} 
Column 1    &   Column 2 \\
\py{tTableData()}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\py{Temp}
\py{Temp}

\end{document}
```

I have found that on the first latex compile action, the .pytxcode file is generated correctly with the following lines generated:

```
=>PYTHONTEX#py#default#default#1#inline##20#
Temp
=>PYTHONTEX#py#default#default#2#inline##26#
tTableData()
=>PYTHONTEX#py#default#default#3#inline##30#
Temp
=>PYTHONTEX#py#default#default#4#inline##31#
Temp
```

After running pythontex.py and recompiling the document with latex, the following errors are generated (snipped from the log file):

```
./testfile.tex:26: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> c@\pytx@counter 

l.26 \py{tTableData()}

./testfile.tex:26: Undefined control sequence.
 ...ssage  LaTeX Error: No counter '\pytx@counter 
                                                  ' defined.

See the LaTeX ...
l.26 \py{tTableData()}

./testfile.tex:26: LaTeX Error: No counter '' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.26 \py{tTableData()}

./testfile.tex:26: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pytx@counter 

l.26 \py{tTableData()}
```

The .pytxcode file now has the following lines:

```
=>PYTHONTEX#py#default#default#1#inline##20#
Temp
=>PYTHONTEX#py#default#default#2#inline##26#
tTableData()
=>PYTHONTEX#py#default#default#2#inline##30#
Temp
=>PYTHONTEX#py#default#default#3#inline##31#
Temp
```

Note the duplicate entries for #2 in lines #26 and #30.

If the itemized list is removed (but `\py{Temp}` is left in place), everything appears to run fine.

Any ideas on why this is occurring?

I am running texlive 2012 and pythontex v. 0.11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug related to PythonTeX's counters.  I'll fix it in the next release, which will be out in a few days.

In the meantime, you can fix this by opening `pythontex.sty` and replacing every `\edef\pytx@counter` with `\xdef\pytx@counter`.

Comment: @Jamie PythonTeX v0.12 is now out and incorporates the fix.